# How do I recover my local repo after git fetch --all

Tags: git

The remote repo was incorrectly changed using `reset --hard`. And I want to find the old version of it from my local repo.

Unfortunately I have run `git fetch --all` in my local repo and now it's the same with the remote repo.

I have tried `git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}` . But my repo is still the same with the remote repo.

How can I do to recover my local repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you did, at one point, have the "correct" commit for `origin/master` on your local repo, it should be listed in :

```
git reflog origin/master
```

Spot the hash for the correct commit, and use that hash as you see fit :

- if you want to force push back to origin :

```
git push --force-with-lease origin <sha>:master
```

- if you just want to set your local `origin/master` ref, use it in the command you typed :

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master <sha>
```

etc ...

Comment: I have tried 'git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master <sha>', but the HEAD of 'git log ' doesn't change, and the commits record is still same with the incorrect remote repo's. Did I try the wrong method?

Comment: updating `origin/master` will not change your current commit (`HEAD`). When you run `git log --graph --oneline HEAD origin/master`, do you see `origin/master` where you want it to be ?

Comment: (`--graph --oneline` are just convenience options, in my experience they make the output of `git log` waaaay more readable)

Comment: I mean the remote repo was incorrectly changed and the commits records were also  changed. I want to restore my local repo and submit it to rewrite the remote repo.Would this method be work?

Comment: just to make sure I am not guiding you to the wrong result : you have spotted a `<sha>`, does `git log --graph --oneline <sha>` display the history you want to restore to the remote `master` branch ?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure about which commits is correct. But there are some commits lost and that's the problem I want to solve. I'm not sure about is there any method to restore my local repo including local repo's commits records the same as before I run 'git fetch --all'.

Comment: is the remote stored on a known service ? github or gitlab.com ? a local instance of gitlab ?

Comment: It is deployed on bitbucket. And someone else is trying to solve the problem. He caused this problem while solving my merge and I don't know what he did. All I can do is try to find a useful backup for him to restore. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In that case : check bitbucket's GUI, there is somewhere a log of what happened to the remote `master` branch. Look for the bad action, read the log to see what was  the `<sha>` of master *before* that bad action. Once you have that `<sha>`, run `git push --force-with-lease origin <sha>:master` from anyone's machine.

Comment: I will convey your suggestion, and thank you again.